# Words with most and fewest syllables for given length?

Tags: word, english, language

### What is the greatest and least number of syllables that a word of a given length can have?

More precisely, for each word length from 1 letter to 20 letters, find words of that length containing as many and as few syllables as possible.

The concept of a syllable is notoriously hard to define, so let's define the number of syllables to be the *number of distinct vowels in the standard English pronunciation of the word*. Only English dictionary words are allowed. British and American English are both acceptable. Diphthongs count as single vowels, so "I" is a single-syllable word. If a word has more than one acceptable pronunciation differing in number of syllables, choose the most helpful one (e.g. count "squirreled" as 1 syllable rather than 2 since that makes a new record for minimum syllables with 10 letters).
<sub>Let me know if there are any loopholes I've missed!</sub>

---

### Current best

1 letter: min 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), ratio 1
2 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 2 syllables (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), ratio 2
3 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 2 syllables (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), ratio 2
4 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 3 syllables (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), ratio 2
5 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 3 syllables (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), ratio 3
6 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 4 syllables (credit **JoeZ**), ratio 4
7 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 5 syllables (credit **user13433**), ratio 5
8 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 5 syllables (credit **JLee**), ratio 5
9 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 5 syllables (credit **JLee**), ratio 5
10 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **Deusovi**), max 6 syllables (credit **JLee**), ratio 6
11 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **Emrakul**), max 6 syllables (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), ratio 6
12 letters: min 1 syllable (credit **Emrakul**), max 7 syllables (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), ratio 7
13 letters: min 2 syllables (credit **Prem**), max 8 syllables (credit **JLee**), ratio 4
14 letters: min 2 syllables (credit **Prem**), max 8 syllables (credit **JLee**), ratio 4
15 letters: min 3 syllables (credit **JLee**/**Prem**), max 8 syllables (credit **JLee**), ratio 2.666...
16 letters: min 3 syllables (credit **Prem**), max 8 syllables (credit **Prem**), ratio 2.666...
17 letters: min 3 syllables (credit **Prem**), max 8 syllables (credit **Prem**), ratio 2.666...
18 letters: min 4 syllables (credit **Prem**), max 9 syllables (credit **Nathaniel**), ratio 2 .25
19 letters: min 4 syllables (credit **Prem**), max 9 syllables (credit **Prem**), ratio 2.25
20 letters: min 5 syllables (credit **Prem**), max 10 syllables (credit **Prem**), ratio 2

Where two answerers have tied for the same minimum or maximum, I've mentioned both their names in alphabetical order; I don't know who was first, but I assume JLee and Prem are both working independently. I also haven't included the actual words found, since that would make the list much longer. If you want to find the words, scroll down to read (and upvote) the answers below.

Comment: The number of syllables is not difficult to define. Just count the · marks in the Google definition of the word and add 1.

Comment: I think your definition is still ambiguous; English has no "standard pronunciations", and some words are pronounced with a different number of syllables by different speakers (example: *crayon*, for which even Google lists both possibilities, breaking @IanMacDonald's proposal).  You probably need to specify a particular dictionary, and state what to do if that dictionary lists multiple pronunciations with different numbers of syllables.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's a rare enough occurrence that I say why not just take the one that helps most. If you need more syllables, take the one with more, and vice versa. On another note, wow, I have never heard of crayon being pronounced with just one syllable! It seems like it would have to sound like "crane" in that case.

Comment: (Oh, I meant to say: the definition in the puzzle wants to count syllables by counting vowels, but the problem is that pronunciations may differ as to what is a dipthong.  A one-syllable pronunciation of *crayon* makes *ayo* a dipthong; a two-syllable pronunciation makes it two distinct vowels.)

Comment: Give the tick mark to Prem. I am already at 4000, and I don't care that much about rep points anyway.

Comment: @JLee , thanks for your previous comment. I checked what you meant by "already at 4000", and see that, that is the state at which all privileges are granted. Beyond that, it is simply a number.

Comment: @JLee I must admit I haven't UVed your answer yet, since I thought both answers deserve an equal number of UVs. But I will do as soon as I've accepted an answer - promise!

Comment: @Prem When graduation time comes along, people will need 20k to get all privileges. Now I've got that as well, but I see no reason to stop participating! :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Grad time isn't even in the pipeline, according to the last meta post I read. Rep is great, but not very satisfying, at least not to me. What *is* satisfying is either writing an excellent thorough answer OR creating an excellent, challenging, and/or unique puzzle OR even finding a cool puzzle and trying to solve it, even if you don't end up figuring it out. The 'privileges' that come w/ rep aren't that awesome. Basically, they just add more responsibility. In the same way that money corrupts true love in the real world, rep points corrupt the true honorable goals of the site.

Comment: @JLee +1 for criticising rep-whores so poetically :-) But [things have changed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites#comment840524_257614) re. grad time, and having at least 10 questions a day means Puzzling *should* now be considered for graduation!

Comment: @randal'thor question for you... sometimes i notice weird numbers for rep earned, like +1. do +1's for comments give rep points somehow?

Comment: @JLee +1 probably means you've had an upvote on a question (+5) and also 2 downvotes (-4). There's no way of earning exactly 1 rep in a single event - except by reversing your own downvote on an answer, since downvoting answers costs you -1. If you check the rep-change table on your profile, it should tell you exactly why you gained/lost each bit of rep.

Comment: Why the arbitrary limit of 20 letters?

Comment: @Muqo It's fairly arbitrary, but I wanted to have _some_ reasonable upper bound, and I'm pretty sure there aren't any common words with more than 20 letters.

Comment: It does make sense to have an upper bound, but I think you really mean to limit the puzzle to words that have the same number of letters as several other words.  Otherwise, it would be less fun with people submitting the sole ##-letter word as an entry, for example.  By the way, some entries for this puzzle can be found in rec.puzzles from many years ago.  Search for "exceptional number of letters per syllable" [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rec.puzzles/0rpeXPyEP0w/t0O_tZ4bA6IJ).

Comment: @Ian MacDonald - Does the advertising company you mentioned still use "·" marks in its definition of words? I only found cases where it doesn't, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. If it does, I reckon it puts one in *flower* and none in *our*.

Comment: What about POW (/ˌpiː.əʊˈdʌb.əl.juː/) ?

Comment: @FlorianF Acronyms feel like cheating.

Comment: Yeah.  It was an answer to "any loopholes?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For 1, minimum : "I" 1
For 1, maximum : "I" 1

For 2, minimum : "It" 1
For 2, maximum : "Io" 2

For 3, minimum : "Don" 1
For 3, maximum : "Era" 2

For 4, minimum : "Done" 1
For 4, maximum : "Iota" 3

For 5, minimum : "Stone" "Schwa" 1
For 5, maximum : "Anion" 3

For 6, minimum : "Streak" 1
For 6, maximum : "Anonym" "Hawaii" 3

For 7, minimum : "Streaks" 1
For 7, maximum : "Anonymy" 4

For 8, minimum : "Strength" 1
For 8, maximum : "Ignominy" "Abacuses" "Honolulu" 4

For 9, minimum : "Strengths" 1
For 9, maximum : "Abrasions" 4

For 10, minimum : "Squirreled" 1 , **thanks to Deusovi**
For 10, maximum : "Abacterial" "Abiogenist" 5

For 11, minimum : "Broughammed" 1 , **thanks to Emrakul**
For 11, maximum : "Abecedarian" "Abiogeneses" "Aerobiology" "Alcyonarian" 6

For 12, minimum : "Schtroumpfed" 1 , **thanks to Emrakul**
For 12, maximum : "Unisexuality" 7

For 13, minimum : "Scratchboards" "Straightbreds" "Straightboard" "Straightforth" 2
For 13, maximum : "Unideological" "Unreliability" "Monosexuality" 7

For 14, minimum : "Straightboards" 2
For 14, maximum : "Stereoisomeric" "Supersexuality" "Unisexualities" 7

For 15, minimum : "Schlockmeisters" "Straightforthly" "Straightforward" 3
For 15, maximum : "Stereoisomerics" "Monosexualities" "Organomercurial" 7

For 16, minimum : "Straightforwards" 3
For 16, maximum : "Stereoisomerical" 8

For 17, minimum : "Straightforthness" 3
For 17, maximum : "Electroanalytical" "Electrophysiology" 8

For 18, minimum : "Forethoughtfulness" 4
For 18, maximum : "Universalizability" 9 , **thanks to Nathaniel**

For 19, minimum : "Straightforwardness" 4
For 19, maximum : "Extraterritoriality" 9

For 20, minimum : "Forethoughtfulnesses" 5
For 20, maximum : "Radioimmunoassayable" 10

**WHEW**

**References**:
http://www.morewords.com/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_longest_English_words_with_one_syllable

Comment: Syllables are essentially about the pronunciation and not the spelling. So "dee" is 1 syllable and "double-you" is 3 syllables and "Hawaiian(s)" is 3 syllables. Other than that, looks good so far!

Comment: I've updated the OP with an honours list and a few clarifications. In particular, British English and American English are both acceptable, so @ Deusovi's "squirreled" also extends to "squirrelled" (which matches @Emrakul's "broughammed")

Comment: @Deusovi For the word **squirreled**, go [**here**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/squirreled?s=t) and click the Syllables button to see that it is clearly 2 syllables.

Comment: @JLee, similar to how some people pronounce "crayon" with only one syllable, I'm sure there are people that choose to pronounce *squirreled* as *sq**world***.

Comment: @IanMacDonald That's the exact example I had in my head as I thought about the 2-syllable-ness of squirreled. Really, to me, world is one of those words that is already kinda on the fence between 1 and 2 syllables, and then, adding the sq in place of the w definitely (in my opinion), makes it sound like 2 syllables, even though I am one of the people that pronounce squirreled as sqworld!

Comment: There is a two-syllable word with 15 letters—it’s even mentioned in the Wikipedia article linked to in the answer here: **halfpennyworths** is, at least optionally, /ˈheɪpərθs/ or /ˈheɪpərðz/.

Comment: What about heterosexuality for a 15 letter 8 syllable word?  That beats the current 15 letter 7 syllable words.

Answer (score 6):

WIP (Work in Progress)

Well, to start,

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't Strengths be 9? You could probably cover 1-9 that way.

Comment: OK, that's it for now. I've got to leave the house for many hours. I'm not sure when/if I will be able to finish this...

Comment: Nice job so far! I was going to disagree on the number of syllables for aa and acai, but having looked them up, I found that you're right. I'm learning plenty of new words here :-)

Comment: You could use "squirreled" for 10.

Comment: rand said diphthongs count as a single vowel, so "açai" is only 2. You could use "area" instead.

Comment: Also, "areola" is 4 syllables for 6 letters.

Comment: @Deusovi squirreled is [2 syllables also](https://www.google.com/search?q=squirreled&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), right?

Comment: @JLee Nope, one. /skwərld/

Comment: I've updated the OP with an honours list and a few clarifications. So far you seem to be doing best on finding words with *most* syllables while Prem and others are beating you on finding words with *fewest* syllables. Keep up the good work! :-D

Comment: @Deusovi Click the link in my last comment and notice the dot that separates the word. That denotes that it has 2 syllables. You cannot depend on the space being in the pronunciation guide, as in [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=squirreled&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=define+feature).

Comment: For 6 letters could be myopia - see  per JoeZ already have 4 - that was shortsighted (:

Comment: Apart from areola and myopia for 6 letters 4 syllables, there are several others: "aviary", "apiary", and my favourite, "idiocy". (There are also the proper nouns Iouea and Azalea.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a 9 syllable word with only 18 letters: universalizability.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! I've edited this into the currently accepted answer for you.

Comment: +1, for improving the answer. I have credited you at the relevant point.

Answer (score 3):

[Ionia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionia): 4 syllables in 5 letters. A little bit obscure and no longer existing as a region of the world, but I still think it counts.

Answer (score 2):

Oxyopia is 5 for 7. Doing six syllables for 8 might be possible.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, and nice job on oxyopia! I'm about to start adding an honours list for those who found the current best words...

Answer (score 1):

For 9, maximum : "idiolalia" 6
For 17, maximum : "paleoepidemiology" 10
For 20, maximum : "paleoepidemiological" 11

Answer (score 0):

I found this post while confirming something I researched several years back.  I write puzzles for my board game shop, and upon seeing the Mayfair game titled "Oceania" it all came flooding back.

I once hypothesized that there may be a word that would trigger a "spelling bee haiku".  I.e. a 5-syllable, 7-letter word (no 'w') that if given in a spelling bee would result in the contestent uttering a haiku.

Oceania
o-c-e-a-n-i-a
Oceania

I found oxyopia & Oceania.  Not sure if you'll accept proper nouns.  Let me know if any others are found!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Loaded Question! Thanks for taking the time to share your story, however on Puzzling (and the other Stack Exchanges) it is best to format your answer such that it can be seen more easily of how it fits and answers the question (Similar to some of the previous answers to this question), since this is deemed a "Question and Answer" website. You are free to share other information  with your answer as well, just make sure other that read it can 'pick out' the important information easily.

Answer (score 0):

'iff', meaning 'if and only if' is a 3 letter word with 5 syllables.  It is important to distinguish it from 'if' and for this reason it is always pronounced with the full five syllables. The Meriam online dictionary has the pronunciation correct (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iff).