# The ANEMONE puzzle

Tags: word, language

The word ANEMONE has only seven letters, but four syllables; this gives $1.75$ letters per syllable on average.

Can you find another English word with

- that is not a proper name
- that has at least four syllables
- that has an average number of letters per syllable below $1.75$

(If there are different solutions with the same average then the one with more consonants gets the prize. If $y$ is pronounced as vowel it counts as a vowel. Otherwise I count $y$ as a consonant.)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but some answers are given [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16760/words-with-most-and-fewest-syllables-for-given-length).

Comment: I was all excited about the word aa until I reread the rules and saw the four syllable requirement. So much for a 0.5 score.

Comment: I wish that three-syllable words were allowed because I would submit `W` with a score of $0.\overline{33}$ although it's questionable if that counts as a *word*.

Comment: BINGO - 5 syllables, 1 letter per syllable -- b-i-n-g-o

Comment: Areola gives 1.5 as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A word with 6 letters, 4 syllables (1.5 ratio):

> Idiocy

Comment: I moved some of your text outside of the spoiler to be a little more attractive for reading.

Answer (score 12):

My answer (ratio 1.4):

> [Oxyopia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oxyopia)//[Oogonia](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oogonia) (5 syllables - 1.4 letters per syllable)
>  Myopia - nearsightedness(4 syllables - 1.5 letters per syllable)
>  You'd also have Opiomania (opium addiction) and Oniomania (desire to shop)
>  (6 syllables, 9 letters, 1.5 ratio)
>  Oceanic/Ammonia (4 syllables - 1.75 letters per syllable)
>  [Iouea](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Iouea)  (4 syllables - 1.25 letters per syllable)

Comment: I removed Oceania, I realised it probably counted as a proper name. I'll admit I was originally confused as to the difference between a proper name and a proper *noun* . Turns out all proper nouns are proper names.

Comment: I think your link to the last one is incorrect.

Comment: Oops, thanks! But I just realized its a proper noun (and thus proper name ... *sad face*)

Comment: Is that a word that is entirely vowels and uses all of them? Ugh. I think I need to lie down.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar of course not, that would be ridiculous. It doesn't use 'Y' (vowel usage)

Answer (score 8):

A word with 6 letters and 4 syllables (1.5 letters per syllable):

> **[Aviary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/aviary)**

Answer (score 8):

10 letters, 6 syllables (1.66), not the best, but a fitting entry

> Actiniaria (the scientific order of the anemone)

Comment: I like this just because it fits with the original word. : )

Answer (score 7):

Another 6 letter 4 syllable: (1.5)

> Acuity

Answer (score 5):

A common word with 10 letters and 6 syllables. (1.67 ratio)

> aficionado

And just for fun, I believe these are words with the worst ratio: 10 letters with only 1 syllable (10.0 ratio):

> strengthed, scraunched

Answer (score 3):

A word with 6 letters and 4 syllables (ratio of 1.5):

> Myopia

Answer (score 3):

## 14 letters/8 syllables (ratio 1.75):

> [utilitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism)
>  [egalitarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egalitarianism)

Answer (score 2):

WC. 2 letters, 4 syllables, 0.5 ratio. An english word, not a proper noun.

Initialisms are the way to go here, but I can't think of others which have a high proportion of W's and which aren't proper nouns.

Comment: AC would be 5 syllables

Comment: @Spacemonkey not as ordinarily pronounced.

Comment: Air/Con/di/tion/ing ?

Comment: @Spacemonkey A/C. Using initialisms is *bending* the rules, but unpacking them to their original meaning would be going too far.

Comment: Ah..... wasn't entirely sure what you meant by initialisms

Answer (score 2):

Here is a website that can answer a lot of these questions with a really concise URL syntax: yougowords.com

- 7 letters and 4 syllables: http://www.yougowords.com/7-letters/4-syllables (ability, apology)
- 6 letters and 4 syllables: http://www.yougowords.com/6-letters/4-syllables (utopia, apiary)
- 8 letters and 5 syllables: http://www.yougowords.com/8-letters/5-syllables (academia, obituary)

Note, a lot of them seem to be wrong, such as *alien*, which has three syllables instead of four.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple words: 7 Letter 4 syllable.

> anatomy idiotic  analogy anxiety atypical unusual biology zoology

Answer (score -1):

14 letters and 4 syllables (ratio of 1.75):

wordprocessors

Comment: umm thats a 3.5 ratio.....

Comment: You don't need the s, but that still leaves 3.25.

Comment: Maybe if you dropped the "word" from processors and tried to sell *CPU* as a word... But that's a big stretch that opens the door to a lot of 1:1 abbreviation/acronym mumbo jumbo.  As it is, this just leaves me confused.

Comment: Yeah, my answer would have been "cm" (four syllables, two letters, score 0.5) but alas.