# What's the minimum number of five letter words that form a haiku, if it's possible at all?

Tags: english, poetry, wordle

Inspired by [Wordle](https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html), I wondered if it's possible to have a Wordle game that forms a [haiku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiku)? The question is in two parts:

- Is it possible to form a Haiku using only five letter English words (e.g. using words in the [SOWPODS](https://www.wordgamedictionary.com/sowpods/) list)?
- If so, what is the minimum number of five letter words required to do so?

As reflected [in another question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16760/words-with-most-and-fewest-syllables-for-given-length) identifying the number of syllables in a given word depends on accent. I'd be inclined to say "where the number of syllables in a word is determined according to either a [Standard American Accent](https://mylanguagebreak.com/is-there-a-standard-american-accent-can-you-learn-it/) or [Standard British Accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A previous puzzling [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16760/words-with-most-and-fewest-syllables-for-given-length) strongly suggests that five letter words have at most three syllables.

So given the Haiku requirement of 5+7+5=17 syllables, it doesn't appear possible, as at least two words are required for each of five-syllable lines, leaving only two words (maximum six syllables) to form the seven-syllable line.

If you take liberties with Haiku form then you could split a word across two lines and get something that *sorta* works.

> ```
> mafia opi-       (3+2=5)
> -um usual edema    (1+3+3=7)
> alarm media       (2+3=5)
> ```

**Translation:**
Crime-family's drugs commonly produce swelling of the ankles. This concerned journalists.

Answer (score -1):

So, after a bit of research. The lowest number of 5-letter words required to make a haiku is

> 6

How come?

> Well, the maximum number of syllables in a 5-letter word is 4 ([iouea](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Iouea)) Given haikus follow a 5 - 7 - 5 pattern, using 2 words for the first 5 syllables, 2 others (4 syllables and 3) for the next 7, and 2 others for the final 5 syllables.
>  Which makes it just small enough to fit in a Wordle game!